# In Flutter place a scrollable list that uses remaining space but is not the last widget in the list of slivers

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

New to flutter and struggling to achieve a layout whereby actions remain at the bottom of a view and there is a scrollable list above them that uses the space remaining after some sibling widgets take their cut. Something like that shown below:

[image]

I have seen in the docs that a SliverGrid is preferable to using many SliverToBoxAdapter widgets but so far whichever tact I try I just end up with RenderBox errors on the list unless I wrap it with a fixed height container which is not what I am after.

SliverFillRemaining would be perfect if it didn't need to come at the bottom of the rest of the widgets.

Code so far as below, however I would appreciate any advice on any approach that achieves the desired layout. I expect there is a dead simple way to do this but I cant see it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Slivers Headache',
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            // an app bar
            const SliverAppBar(
              primary: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  title: Text('Slivers')
              )
            ),
            // a text field
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: TextField(
              controller: TextEditingController(text: 'Text1'),
              onChanged: (value) => {},
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder()),
              )
            ),
            // another text field
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: TextField(
                controller: TextEditingController(text: 'Text1'),
                onChanged: (value) => {},
                decoration: const InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
              )
            ),
            // a checkbox
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: CheckboxListTile(
                tristate: false,
                title: const Text('checkbox'),
                value: false,
                onChanged: (bool? value) => {},
              )
            ),
            // wish I could make a scrollable list view here that takes up remaining vertical space
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Wish I could fill and scroll $index'),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 3,
              )
            ),
            // some actions
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text('Confirm'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('Confirmed');
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text('Cancel'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('Cancelled');
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  )
                ]
              )
            )
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold has bottomSheet property which is like bottom navbar. It will always stay at bottom and top of the content beneath it. (This should have been a comment but i dont have enough rep for it :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your input made me discover the scaffold 'persistentFooterButtons' property which along with SliverFillRemaining will do very nicely for the problem at hand mate... I am still hoping that somebody could post a solution or some hints that uses slivers as originally described to see if it is possible so that I can better understand the workings of slivers and an approach for differing sliver sizes and scrolls etc.

Comment: Happy to help. I've used this in my project but I may also change it with any incoming answers.